# Making Draft before submitting question

Tags: support, drafts

Is there a function to keep draft before submitting a question?
If there is not, could you consider to implement it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can post your question and delete it right away. Then edit and undelete it later.

Ultimately, it's best to simply use a Markdown editor on your computer and post the final result when you're done.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer. I understand.

Comment: @user3171796 Well, there is a draft saved in your browser's local storage. You should see a "draft saved" message or something. I'm just not sure how long it's kept etc.

Comment: Its not just local, I had a test post follow me across systems.

Comment: I wasn't aware there wa a "Markdown editor" available. I usually compose larger posts in a plain text editor on my computer and it is always a hassle to get the formatting right without being able to see what it looks like. A Markdown editor on my computer would really be handy. Where is it available?

Comment: @KevinFegan: There are several available. I'm on Windows and use [MarkdownPad](http://markdownpad.com/) myself.

Answer (score 3):

As long as you don't delete it, SE seems to do some sort of autosaving automatically. I had a unposted, nonsense post follow me across systems. If you want to ask *multiple* questions as drafts, you have an issue, but as long as you're logged in, your partially asked question will follow you around.

Comment: Reference: [Allow questions to be saved as drafts prior to posting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting)

Comment: Wouldn't this be a dupe of that?

Comment: If we were on Meta Stack Overflow …

Comment: eh. Clearly I am distracted

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a function to keep draft before submitting a question?

Not yet, I am afraid. However as long as you do not delete it, there would be a temporary memory in our browser. One of the alternative solution is to use editor, eg. https://stackedit.io/

> If there is not, could you consider to implement it?

I hope the Stack overflow developer can consider this brilliant idea. I should think more to post the question when it is not ready. Presumably it will leads to down vote.

Keep inspiring!

Comment: Have you read the other posts? There *is* a draft feature.

Comment: Hi @slhck which posts are those? Would you explain me more, please?

Comment: Firstly, the answer by Journeyman Geek on the very same question, and [Allow questions to be saved as drafts prior to posting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting)

Comment: @slhck : I have not read it before

Comment: @slhck : Meanwhile, can you suggest something to me so that this answer can be improved, please? It would be much better, I suppose.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, exactly. Your answer claims that there's no such feature (which isn't true) and your second paragraph just hopes that Stack Exchange implements the feature (which is already implemented). Perhaps it would be better to read other answers before posting your own to prevent that kind of confusion.

Comment: @slhck : You give a good advise for me. It is valuable. Thank you

Comment: @slhck : Can you show me where is the "save draft button" please? http://i.imgur.com/FBJkYws.jpg , But this is not so hurry request

Comment: There is no dedicated button. The draft will be saved automatically in the background. A "draft saved" (or similar) message will appear.

Comment: @slhck Yes indeed I should improve my question. I aspire and support the Idea to have that **Dedicated Button** an I am deserved for a down vote for that.